# скролл не там, где надо

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка, jscrollpane

Постараюсь описать детально. В общем у меня на странице есть блок со скроллом
Вот нарисовал схему:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что мы не сможем долистать до конца страницы, если не наведем курсор вне блоков со скроллами. Да мы даже до конца скроллов тех не попадем, потому что они еще внизу за пределами экрана продолжаются. Логично, что при наведении на блоки со скроллом у меня скролится именно этот блок. А вся страница не скролится, что и порождает проблему. Я с этим еще не сталкивался, подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему. Через js скорее всего, но как?

Comment: А в чем проблема то? Когда блок со скроллом пролистается до самого низа - пойдет скроллинг страницы. Это логичное поведение

Comment: но скролл не происходитю Он происходит только тогда, когда я курсор отведу от блока внутреннего. Даже если тот прокручен на максимум. Может есть кастомный скролл, который с такой проблемой на ты?

Comment: решил проблему использованием разных плагинов.. Но больше похоже на костыль

Comment: В демке jscrollpane все работает именно так как я написал. Да и во всех остальных плагинах

Comment: @РашенБеар в общем перешел на perfect sidebar. Не скролл, а сказка

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить блокам

```
overflow: hidden;
```

а при наведение

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Пока вы на них конкретно не наведёте, они скролица и не будут и вы спокойно сможете скролить всю страницу.

Comment: проблема в том, что они на пол страницы

Comment: и да, скроллить их это нормально. Но вот по окончание скролла внутреннего блока скрол внешнего не происходит